# Word association search in Apache Lucene

Tags: java, search, lucene, machine-learning

I have a requirement to associate math terms that come under a common topic. For e.g. angles, cos, tan, etc., should relate to trigonometry. So when a user searches for angles, triangles, etc. the search should present results related to trigonometry as well. Can anyone provide leads on how to do this in Apache Lucene?

Answer (score 2):

There is a [classification api](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/classification/org/apache/lucene/classification/package-summary.html) which includes **K-nearest neighbors** and **naive Bayes** models.

You would first use the `train()` method with your training set.  Once the classifier is trained use the `assignClass()` method to classify a given string.

For a training set you could use Wikipedia pages for your given classes.

After you give those two a try you could make use of the [Classifier](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/classification/org/apache/lucene/classification/Classifier.html) interface to build a competing model.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the associations, you can just add them to the index for the specific terms -- i.e. indexing 'cos' as 'cos', 'trigonometry'.

Also if you know the associations, you could index the parent term and all of the sibling terms -- i.e. indexing 'cos' as 'trigonometry', 'cos', 'sin', etc. This sounds more like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Josh S.'s good answer, you can also take a more direct approach, of generating your own synonyms dictionary, e.g. see [Match a word with similar words using Solr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978302/match-a-word-with-similar-words-using-solr)